# UFW - what is the meaning of 'Rule changed after normalization'

Tags: ufw

I issue the following :

```
# ufw allow from <ip address>
```

And get the response:

```
WARN: Rule changed after normalization
Rule added (v6)
```

I am familiar with the term 'normalization' in relational database structuring but I am curious how this is applied to the UFW rules. The rule I requested is subsequently listed just as I entered it

```
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW IN    <ip address>
```

What has happened in this process of normalization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer, but I do have an example. Note that `man ufw` explains:

> Because rules are normalized by ufw, rules may look different than the originally added rule.

In my case, ufw had to normalize the rule I gave it because it was an IP + subnet (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx) where **the IP was more specific than the subnet required**; *e.g.,*

```
# ufw allow from 192.168.123.8/24
```

The `/24` subnet says "include all IP addresses that match `192.168.123.xxx`, so the `.8` at the end is unnecessary: `192.168.123.0/24` means the same thing without the extra "significant digits". Thus, ufw normalizes my rule by converting the `.8` to `.0`.

Not sure what other kinds of normalization ufw performs, but you can probably observe what happened simply by comparing the rule you gave to ufw and the rules it reports in `ufw status`.

Comment: Ah yes. Just tested: you're right. I must have inadvertently entered a rule like that. I don't have the original entry but that is a likely error.